# how to center align a box to the window size?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I would like to center align a div(`cen`) which is inside another div(`imp`)

Here is the code example

```
.imp
{
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
        background-color: black;
        position: fixed;
        top:0;
        bottom:0;
}
```

above is the main div now the div which should be center is given below

```
    .cen
   {
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    padding:5px;
    width:auto;
    height:auto;

   }
```

Here is my question how to align `.cen` to middle of the browser?
Having margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; brings to center but not from the top.I have given top to 50% and left 50% then also i can't align it center because the content inside `.cen` bigger so it appears bottom right of the window. Any clue or idea?

Comment: So you want to vertically center it?

Comment: Do you also want to horizantally center it?

Comment: @hungerstar the Div and its content should appear at the center of the browser window

Comment: Try this too http://css-tricks.com/centering-percentage-widthheight-elements/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As this needs to be responsive, It can be only achieved using Javascript.

```
var cen = document.getElementsByClassName('cen')[0];
var imp = document.getElementsByClassName('imp')[0];
cen.style.marginTop = ((imp.offsetHeight / 2) - (cen.offsetHeight / 2)) + "px";
```

Call the above function in both `resize` and `load` events.

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/venkateshwar/jLBcQ/1/)

Also, check **[Calc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc)** CSS3 property. will be helpful if you are aware of the height of the child element.

Comment: For my curiosity, it works fine, but when you re-size your browser window, it again loses its alignment until you refresh the page. So is it possible to get the same alignment in case of browser re-size?

Comment: @Mr_Green Thanks problem solved but can't it be done using css alone?

Comment: @raj, just added a CSS solution.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a CSS solution.  You'll need to wrap your `.imp` div within another div that has 100% height of the window.

The main key here is the `display` values of `table` for the outer div `.imp` and `table-cell` for the inner div `.cen` along with `vertical-align: middle`.

**CSS**

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}
html, body, #wrapper {
  height: 100%;
}
#wrapper { 
    background-color: red; 
    display: table; 
    width: 100%; }
.imp {
  min-height: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.cen { 
    background-color: orange; 
}
```

**HTML**

```html
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="imp">
        <div class="cen">.cen</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort.Working fine. i upvoted.could you explain me a bit so that i can understand and use the technique whenever i need:)

Comment: What we are doing is telling the `divs` to behave like a table.  Actual table cells, `<td>` vertically align items to the middle by default along with inhereting height (which happen a number of ways).  

In this case your `.imp` div will be 100% height of it's parent element due to `min-height` (which may not be the full height of the browser window) and will behave like a `<table>` since we set it's `display` property to `table`.  Your `.cen` div is then told to behave like a `<td>`.  In order for `display: table-cell` to work it's parent element needs `display: table`.